# Android - share multiple intent with both images and videos. what to use in setType()?

Tags: android, android-intent

This is how we share multiple images:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.setType("image/");
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUrisList);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share imageS using"));
```

And if we want to share multiple videos we can use intent.setType("video/"); instead.

But what type should be used if the files ar mixed images and videos ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a system that can handle both video and images. Normally that's something that can handle video (which also happens to handle images). So you would use the type `"video/"`

Comment: yes i kind of thought of that too... i just  thought that maybe there was a mixed type for this case, hence the question. thnx though